# How to get the latest photo in iPhone Library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my app there is a button, user just click it then the latest photo in library can be retrieved on screen directly. How to get the latest photo in library?

---

2012/02/17

this can get ALAsset

```
void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if(result != nil)
        {

            [self.assets addObject:result];

        }
    };

    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if(group != nil)
        {
            [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        }else{
            self.image = [self getLastImage];

        }

    };
    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock = ^(NSError *myerror){
        NSLog(@"error occour =%@", [myerror localizedDescription]);
    };


    assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator failureBlock:failureblock];
    [assetsLibrary release];
```

To get file date I use this

```
    assetURLArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (ALAsset *asset in self.assets) {
        NSDate * date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
```

Then I found that the latest image always be the top one of assetURLArray, so I finally get the latest one like this

```
if (self.assets && [self.assets count]) {
        ALAsset *asset = [self.assets objectAtIndex:([self.assets count] - 1)];
        CGImageRef ref = [[asset defaultRepresentation]fullResolutionImage];
```

I donno if this is always work... hope any one can prove me.

And there I'm looking for a way to sync thread...

Comment: you can just do `[self.assets lastObject]`, which helpfully returns nil if the count is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet can retrieve an `ALAsset`:

```
void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger   
index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != nil) {
        [self.assets addObject:result];
    }
};

void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group != nil) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    } else {
        self.image = [self getLastImage];
    }
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock = ^(NSError *myerror) {
    NSLog(@"error occour =%@", [myerror localizedDescription]);
};

assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator failureBlock:failureblock];
[assetsLibrary release];
```

To get file date I use this:

```
assetURLArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (ALAsset *asset in self.assets) {
    NSDate * date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
```

Then I found that the latest image always be the top one of `assetURLArray`, so I finally get the latest one like this:

```
if (self.assets && [self.assets count]) {
    ALAsset *asset = [self.assets objectAtIndex:([self.assets count] - 1)];
    CGImageRef ref = [[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage];
```

I don't know if this is always works... I hope someone can clear up my doubts about that.

And there I'm looking for a way to sync thread...

---

2012-04-03 Update

Now I use `NSNotification` to solve this problem:

```
- (void)gotLastImageCallBack {
    if (notifyName) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notifyName object:nil];
    }
}
```

After fetched image, the notification sends call back to related class.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it simply by following method of ALAssetsGroup

```
(void)enumerateAssetsWithOptions:(NSEnumerationOptions)options usingBlock:(ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock)enumerationBlock;**

    applying **NSEnumerationReverse** option

    void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
        {
            if(result != nil)
            {

                [self.assets addObject:result];

            }
        };

        void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
        {
            if(group != nil)
            {
                [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
                [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:assetEnumerator];
            }

        };
        ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock = ^(NSError *myerror){
            NSLog(@"error occour =%@", [myerror localizedDescription]);
        };


        assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator failureBlock:failureblock];
        [assetsLibrary release];


    **Your self.assets array will have latest images**
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get all the photos created date and then sort them by date.

```
- (NSDictionary *) attributesForFile:(NSURL *)anURI {

// note: singleton is not thread-safe
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *aPath = [anURI path];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:aPath]) return nil;

NSError *attributesRetrievalError = nil;
NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:aPath
                           error:&attributesRetrievalError];

if (!attributes) {
   NSLog(@"Error for file at %@: %@", aPath, attributesRetrievalError);
   return nil;
}

NSMutableDictionary *returnedDictionary = 
   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [attributes fileType], @"fileType",
        [attributes fileModificationDate], @"fileModificationDate",
        [attributes fileCreationDate], @"fileCreationDate",
        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:[attributes fileSize]], @"fileSize",
    nil];

return returnedDictionary;
}
```

Comment: thanks but how to get access to photo lib and read all images in every album out?

Comment: hehe, I just want to tell, that actually you gave me a way to research, but finally I found that I can only get the Asset URL, such as assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000477&ext=JPG and with this NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; NSString *aPath = [anURI path]; I can only get file name: asset.JPG. I find another way and you can see my update. Actually the reply above starting me.

Comment: but you still shown me the door. So I vote your answer +1. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *photoAlbum = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[photoAlbum addTarget:self action:@selector(getLatestPhoto:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

 -(void)getLatestPhoto
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupLibrary usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        if ([group numberOfAssets] > 0)
        {
            [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[group numberOfAssets]-1] options:0
                             usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop)
             {

             }];
        }
    }
        failureBlock: ^(NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"No Photo");
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this guys

```
void (^enumerate)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    if ([[group valueForProperty:@"ALAssetsGroupPropertyType"] intValue] == ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos)
    {
        NSLog(@"Camera roll");
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if(result != nil){
                ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [result defaultRepresentation];
                [thumbnailsArray insertObject:rep atIndex:0];
            }

        }];
    }
```