# Check ALAssetsLibrary empty or not

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using ALAssetsLibrary and app getting crashed when it is empty.How do i check whether it is empty  or not?.

```
   -(void)getLastImageName1
{
//    if (val < 10) {

//      NSLog(@"getLastImageName1\n");
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    // Enumerate just the photos and videos group by using ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos.

    last =1;

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

        // Within the group enumeration block, filter to enumerate just photos.
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        if (last == 1) {
//            NSLog(@"last\n");
            last++;
                        // Chooses the photo at the last index
            [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[group numberOfAssets]-1] options:0 usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {

                // The end of the enumeration is signaled by asset == nil.
                if (alAsset) {

                    NSString *lastImgNew = alAsset.defaultRepresentation.filename;
//                    NSLog(@"current img name %@\n",lastImgNew);

                    NSString *plistPath1 = [DOCUMENT_DIR_PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"previouslastimagename.plist"];
                    NSArray *lastImg = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath1];
//                    NSLog(@"get pre lastimg %@\n",lastImg);

//                    NSArray *lastImg = [[DBModel database]getPreviousName];
//                    NSLog(@"get lastImg %@\n",lastImg);

                    if ([lastImg count] != 0) {
//                        NSLog(@"count\n");

                    if ([[lastImg objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:lastImgNew]) {
//                        NSLog(@"img eql\n");
//                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"equal" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
//                        [alert show];

                        [self hideImage];
//                     }    
                    }
                    else
                    {
//                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pre %@ current %@",[lastImg objectAtIndex:0],lastImgNew] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
//                        [alert show];

//                        NSLog(@"img not eql\n");
                        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayAlert) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

                    }
                    }

                }
            }];

        }

    } failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
        // Typically you should handle an error more gracefully than this.
        //            NSLog(@"No groups");
    }];
```

The line which after last++ variable.I am checking lastimage with newscreenshot image to not allow user to use app after taking screenshot

Comment: Can you show us where it is crashing?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'indexSet count or lastIndex must not exceed -numberOfAssets'   This is what i am getting

Comment: are u there?is there solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line that is giving you the error:

```
[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[group numberOfAssets]-1]
```

If there are zero assets then you are setting the index to -1. You can wrap that enum block in a conditional to test if `numberOfAssets` > 0 before proceeding. Also, there are other questions you may find helpful to look at here. Ex.: [How to get the latest photo in iPhone Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290929/how-to-get-the-latest-photo-in-iphone-library)