# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo get Image filename

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to get the image filename from the camera.  I have seen many, many posts about retrieving the filename using UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL or UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL, but that only gets you a filename similar to: //asset/asset.JPG?id=D1D715A8-6956-49FF-AF07-CE60FE93AE32&ext=JPG.  I believe this is because the image is not saved yet, thus a name like img0001.jpg in not available.

Does anyone know how to get the filename?  I am as suing I need to do this after UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I have seen the question asked many times, but none seem to 'really' answer it, they just always give the filename from an image chosen from the picker not from the camera.

Thanks for any help

** UPDATE:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
    {
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        imageView.image = image;
        if (newMedia)
        {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);

            NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

            // define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
            ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
            {
                ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
                NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);
            };
            // get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url (pass in block above)
            ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            [assetslibrary assetForURL:refURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

My code above, but when imageRep filename is logged it is null.

Comment: are you able to get the asset??

Comment: Yes, I get the asset but it does not contain the filename, it only contains asset.jpg.  I believe that is because the image is not saved yet. I will update my post with my code, not sure if that will help, but ya never know.

Comment: MMM YEAP YOU'RE RIGHT HAVE U TRIED TO GET THE LAST SAVED PHOTO NAME?? THEN U COULD BUILD THE NAME OF YOUR NEXT PICTURE...

Comment: Have you tried moving the asset code into the completion callback?

Comment: sorry i didnt realizeed i had the capitals activated

Comment: Jacck Wu - I thought of moving the code, but short of a member variable, I am not sure of the best way to pass the info (NSDictionary) to the completion callback.

Comment: take a look to the selected answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290929/how-to-get-the-latest-photo-in-iphone-library