# PHFetchResults date filter not generating correct results for time range

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdate, phasset

I am trying to fetch images from photo library within the range of two dates and [I am getting the images successfully.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587405/how-to-fetch-images-from-photo-library-within-range-of-two-dates-in-ios) Using PHAsset Library

Now the problem is that am not able to get images between two times of the same day like between 12:10PM to 12:30PM

Using below code

```
    NSDate *startDate = [self getDateForDay:30 andMonth:9 andYear:2016 andHour:12 andMinute:10 andSecond:0];
    NSDate *endDate = [self getDateForDay:30 andMonth:9 andYear:2016 andHour:12 andMinute:30 andSecond:0];
```

--

```
-(NSDate*) getDateForDay:(NSInteger) day andMonth:(NSInteger) month andYear:(NSInteger) year andHour:(NSInteger) hour andMinute:(NSInteger) minute andSecond:(NSInteger) second{
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:day];
[comps setMonth:month];
[comps setYear:year];

[comps setHour:hour];
[comps setMinute:minute];
[comps setSecond:second];
NSCalendar* gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
return date;
}
```

-- And passing those dates to below method to get images

```
    PHFetchResult *result = [self getAssetsFromLibraryWithStartDate:startDate andEndDate:endDate];
```

Dates and time coming correct when i print in log but not getting images

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you set the timezone correctly? The date created here would be in UTC timezone and yours may vary. Make sure you have set the timezone of calendar like `[calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];` before creating a date from it

Comment: And also make sure that you have images in library which exist within the time range

Comment: Check my edited question...ya i have images thats sure

Comment: Now you are creating the date in GMT Timezone. Your Phone's timezone may be different. Are you located in GMT aka UK?

Comment: To test the timezone problem simply extend the date-limits for a couple of hours.

Comment: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] is better because it takes the timezone set on the Device so it should work in any timezone. @rokjarc It will have to be more than a couple hours I believe (+6?) As the OP is probably located in India.

Comment: Ya extended ...but not working @rokjarc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date created here would be in UTC timezone and yours may vary. Which is why the predicate may not return you correct results.

Make sure you have set the timezone of calendar to your system timezone before creating a date from it like:

```
NSCalendar* gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[gregorian setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
```

That will create the date in your local timezone and generate correct results.

Comment: Ya got it ...Thank you so much @NSNoob for your hat-trick help and also my task completed cheers :-)