# How to get the photos according to date in objective c

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I am using **ALAssetsLibrary** to get the photos and display them. But i want the latest picture to be at front(which means sorted according to date-time).Is this possible using **ALAssetsLibrary** ?? If not what could be the possible way to achieve that??

```
ALAssetsLibrary *al = [AssetManager defaultAssetsLibrary];


    [al enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                      usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
     {
         [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
          {
              if (asset)
              {
                [self.assets addObject:asset];

              }

          }
          ];

         NSLog(@"first    %@",self.assets);

         self.assetsR=[[[self.assets reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] mutableCopy];
         [self.collectionData reloadData];
```

Comment: Refer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290929/how-to-get-the-latest-photo-in-iphone-library

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) class

it has onOrder property

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
self.assetsR = [self.assets sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ALAsset *first, ALAsset *second) {

    NSDate * date1 = [first valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
    NSDate * date2 = [second valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];

    return [date2 compare:date1];
}];
```

Comment: can u please explain it....btw i can have lots of images under the picture directory

Comment: On your code self.assets array has all the assests from the asset library. You want to sort  this array based on the date creation. ALAsset class has the property "ALAssetPropertyDate" which holds the asset creation date. So you can use this property to sort the assets.